# python pygame make the alien group move

Tags: python, pygame

Update 12/7

Finally i found the reason why i cant use `Group` to calling the methods , for the method name must `update()` so that the `Group` can calling.

in my codes i modify like this then it worked!!

```
def update(self):
     self.x =self.rect.x + self.speed
     self.rect.x = self.x
def position(aliens):
    aliens.update()
```

=============================================

Edit the question make it clearly

```
def update(self):
            self.x =self.ai.setting.alien_speed_factor
            self.rect.x = self.x

def update_aliens(aliens):
       aliens.update()
```

These two from the book, and i use  it in my codes, for the aliens is a Group it called error #AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'position'

How to make `Group` aliens to execute `update()`???

I am writing script to make the alien group to move, one for my own way and another is from the book, when i refer to the book i found a mistake, i am not sure whether is it wrong.

Book "**Python Crash Course**" page 243

I use

```
def update(aliens):
    for alien in aliens:
        alien.position()
```

instead of the code from book:

```
def update(aliens):
        aliens.position()
```

which returns

```
>> AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'position'
```

then the runing the script is correct, so is this a mistake in book? or i use the wrong way to run the original codes?

here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pygame as p


class Setting():
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.w=width
        self.h=height
        self.flag=p.RESIZABLE
        self.screen=p.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h),self.flag)
        p.display.set_caption("Muhaha")



class Alien(p.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pic=p.image.load("../image/ship.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.image=p.transform.smoothscale(pic,(100,100))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.rect.x=(self.rect.width)
        self.speed=1
    def create(self,setting,aliens):
        spacex=setting.w-(self.rect.x)*2
        spacey=(setting.h)/2-self.rect.y
        alien_number=int(spacex/(2*(self.rect.width)))
        alien_row=int(spacey/(2*(self.rect.height)))
        for row in range(alien_row):
           for number in range(alien_number):
               alien=Alien()
               alien.rect.x=alien.rect.x+2*alien.rect.width*number
               alien.rect.y=alien.rect.y+2*alien.rect.height*row
               aliens.add(alien)

    def position(self):
        self.x =self.rect.x + self.speed
        self.rect.x = self.x
    def update(aliens):
        aliens.position()        #AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'position'
                                 #i think the correct code is>> for alien in aliens:
                                 #                              alien.position()

    def blit(setting,aliens):
        aliens.draw(setting.screen)

def game():
    p.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)
    alien=Alien()
    aliens=p.sprite.Group()
    alien.create(setting,aliens)
    while True:
         for event in p.event.get():
             if event.type == p.QUIT:
                 sys.exit()
         setting.screen.fill((255,0,0))
         Alien.blit(setting,aliens)
         Alien.update(aliens)
         p.display.flip()
game()
```

Comment: What book is this from? I'm the author of Python Crash Course, which includes a project called Alien Invasion. This looks like it's from a plagiarized versoin of the book; this code has some of the same calculations, but it is organized quite differently.

Comment: @japhyr hi in page 243 ```def update(self)  self.x =self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor  self.rect.x = self.x``` then ```def update_aliens(aliens)  aliens.update()``` aliens is a Group

Comment: @japhyr i found the reason!!! if i want to use Group to  calling the methods that it name must be ```def update()```，i change it in my codes it worked ,and it not bug in book, it's my bug

Comment: I'm glad to hear you've sorted out the issue you were having. But for anyone reading this post, this is not the code from Python Crash Course. It's either from a poorly plagiarized version of the book, or this is someone's independent attempt at restructuring the code. For anyone who's curious, the [actual code from the book is posted here](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e). There are multiple versions of the game in the folders corresponding to chapters 12-14.

Comment: I have edited the question, for that code it created by myself， i know it may really horrible, i refer to the book then base on the understanding write the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems like a bug. And to be honest, the entire code looks horrible.

As a first step, remove the `blit` and `position` functions from the `Alien` class, change the `update` function to this:

```
def update(self):
    self.x = self.rect.x + self.speed
    self.rect.x = self.x
```

and in the main loop, instead of

```
     Alien.blit(setting,aliens)
     Alien.update(aliens)
```

do

```
    aliens.update()
    aliens.draw(setting.screen)
```

Calling `update` on a `Group` will call the `update` of all `Sprite` instances in that `Group`, so there's not need to iterate over all sprites manually.

In the same vein, calling `draw` on a `Group` will draw all sprites in that `Group` to the `Surface` passed as argument (usually the screen surface). Again, there's no need to do this in the `Alien` class, which is supposed to represent a single sprite.

Some other issues:

- the image for the `Alien` sprite is loaded from disk every time an new instance is created
- there's no FPS limit, so the game does not run at a constant speed
- it's common to name your main function, well, 'main'
- an instance of `Alien` is created to just create more instances with the `create` instance method, and then the `update` function is used like a class method